# Correct: returning valid data of nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Need clarification: I wrote this class method to load an image. In the event that the image doesn't exist, is returning `nil` the way to handle the return value or would it be clearer to return an uninitialized `UIImage` (still nil but clearer)?

```
+ (UIImage*)loadImageByName:(NSString*)name
{
    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath];

    if (fileExists){
        UIImage* tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
        return tmpImage;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Returning `nil` is a fine way to indicate that no image could be loaded.

Comment: nil is nil. There is no gain when you "assign" nil to a variable of type UIImage and then return the nullified variable instead. #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common. Many of Foundation and UIKit methods do the same. Just document that, on error, the method returns `nil`. [`NSData dataWithContentsofFile:` for example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

As recommendation, to guard against what might a directory, you can use this method ([ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

```
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory;
```

Ex:

```
BOOL isdir;

if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath isDirectory:&isdir] && (! isdir) )
    // file exists and not a directory
else
    // handle error like mentioned in another answer
```

Answer (score 2):

return nil, that is the correct way to indicate that the operation can't be completed...
then the following code works:

```
UIImage * someImage;
if ((someImage = [YourClass loadImageByName:@"donkey"]))
{
//do something
}else{
//failure
}
```

also if you wanted to you could include some sort of feedback

```
+ (UIImage*)loadImageByName:(NSString*)name error:(NSError **)err
{
    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath];

    if (fileExists){
        UIImage* tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
        return tmpImage;
    }else{
        if(err)
         {
             *err = [NSError someErrorMethodHere...];
         }
    }
    return nil;
}
```